# Sitecore tries to reload the page when saving in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

In a component I have rich-text with some text (no special characters). After I edit the text I press save and the page tries to reload with a warning.

[image: Reload popup warning]

Pressing on "Reload" will discard the change, and clicking on "Don't Reload" will leave the page with the Sitecore popup:

[image: Broken links popup]

I am using: Sitecore.NET 8.0 (rev. 150812)

Why does Sitecore force a page reload?

Comment: Sys, what exeperience do you get if you fix the broken images that the page is referencing first?

Comment: What browser version are you using? Is this happening in all browsers or only one specific version?

Comment: @TobyGutierrez this happens on Chrome, Internet Explorer and Firefox, so it doesn't seems to be browser-specific

Comment: Have you checked for any item:saved events that may be triggered when saving components with rich text fields?

Answer (score 6):

It is worth reviewing the validation rules on the `Image Field`. The validation rules have certain types of behaviour based on the result of the validation. The following are potential results:

> The “Result” parameter determines the default result value of a validation.
>
> Possible values are:
>
> Valid = Green, everything is fine
>
> Suggestion = Bright Orange, hmm, take a look at this
>
> Warning = Orange, you should do something about this
>
> Error = Red, this is an error you know
>
> CriticalError  = Red, user is warned before saving
>
> FatalError = Red, user cannot save item before validator is cleared

Source: [Source for quoted text and more information on validators](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/)

The dialog stating "Changes you made may not be saved". This can occur if someone has set a validator that requires the `Image field` to not be a) pointing to an image that is missing or b) no image.

So as @aseabridge suggested it is worth trying to point the image field to an image that exists. The other option is to review the validations set on the field and remove them if they should not exist. Worth noting they were placed in for a reason, make sure if your removing you don't break any potential business process reasons.